Negative Jacobian for small finite element in AceFEM
I want to make simulation for 1 hexahedral finite element of dimensions 1mm x 1mm x 1mm. I need to use SI units (metres) as below in the code
<< AceFEM`;
H = 0.001; 
SMTInputData[];

SMTAddDomain[
  "imp", {"ML:", "SE", "D3", "H1", "DF", "HY", "H1", 
   "D", {{"NeoHooke", "WA"}}}, {"E *" -> 20000 }];
SMTMesh["imp", 
  "H1", {1, 1, 
   1}, {{{{0, 0, 0}, {H, 0, 0}}, {{0, H, 0}, {H, H, 0}}}, {{{0, 0, 
      H}, {H, 0, H}}, {{0, H, H}, {H, H, H}}}}];
SMTAnalysis[];
SMTShowMesh[]

Why do I obtain the following warning?
WARNING: Negative Jacobian: 1.*10^-9 Possible clockwise (incorrect!) direction of master mesh. See also: SMTAddMesh.
What can I do to simulate the element without changing its dimensions?

You try to build a cube with only two tetrahedrons!?

No, the cube is one hexahedron (element H1).

Then I misunderstood "1 cubic finite element of dimensions 1mm x 1mm x 1mm" ?

I changed in question "cubic" for "hexahedral", I hope it is clear now. I want to simulate a cube specimen using one hexahedral finite element.

The build in Jacobian check is for your case to restrictive. Received warning can be simply ignored in your case.

Thank you for the response. That's right that I made mistake in numbering. However for the correct sequence and commad SMTAddMesh taken from tutorial :
SMTAddMesh[
Hexahedron[{{0, 0, 0}, {H, 0, 0}, {H, H, 0}, {0, H, 0}, {0, 0,
H}, {H, 0, H}, {H, H, H}, {0, H, H}}], "A", "H1", {1, 1, 1}];
there still is a problem with negative Jacobian for H=0.001 which disappears for higher values of H, for example H=0.01. So the problem is still not solved...

Actually, I checked the old pdf tutorial for AceFEM from 2016 and the sequence of nodes for (now obsolete) command SMTMesh[] used in the question is correct (page 40).

You are right. Numbering is correct for the obsolete SMTMesh[]  command. The actual reason is too restrictive check of Jacobian.
